# Send mail via SMTP (ideally using OAuth 2.0) in a Google Marketplace App

Tags: python, oauth, gmail, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

Using the [docs and python libraries google provided in the oauth2client.py](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) along with the [oauth2.py library and docs](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) I managed to successfully send mail via a user's gmail account by authenticating them through OAuth2.0. I created a project in google apis and was able to get the keys and other params needed to correctly authenticate and send mail.

Now I am trying to achieve the same goal but with a Google Marketplace App. The end-goal is that a domain administrator could add our app to their Google Apps domain so that each user would not need to go through the authentication process and our app would 'automatically' be authorized to send mail on their behalf.

The first problem came in that when registering an App in the marketplace, I was given the client key and secret, but no `redirect_uri`, like I was given in the other project. This means I was unable to authenticate using their `OAuth2WebServerFlow` class. This lead to some hours of searching and conflicting answers and broken links within Google's documentation. [This doc](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v1/marketplace#oauth2) leads me to believe that Marketplace Apps don't support OAuth 2.0 and that I would need to go back to using a 2-legged OAuth 1.0 authentication. But it was updated over a year ago and all the other Google docs tell me strongly not to use OAuth 1.0 as it's been deprecated.

Is re-writing all new code (not being able to use the same libraries or anything) to use OAuth 1.0 the only way to be able to do this with a Marketplace App? Is there another way and if not, any advice on leveraging the existing code or how best to do in in their current system?

A short snippet of how I'm doing it currently using OAuth 2.0:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id="xxx",
    client_secret="xxx",
    scope="https://mail.google.com/",
    user_agent="mytest/0.1",
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback"
)

authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

and on return

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(request.args['code'])
storage = Storage(request.user.email)
storage.put(credentials)
```

and to send the mail

```
conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.googlemail.com', 587)
conn.set_debuglevel(True)
conn.ehlo('test')
conn.starttls()
auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (user_address, credentials.access_token)
conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string))

header = 'To:' + recipient_address + '\n'
header += 'From:' + user_address + '\n'
header += 'Subject: Oauth test Email \n'
header += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n'
msg = header + '\n ' + "Waka waka" + ' \n\n'

conn.sendmail(user_address, recipient_address, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I had 50 points, I'd answer with a comment, since this won't be a full answer.*

I've been wrestling with similar problems.  I came to the realization that I was better off (more in control) if I interacted with the APIs directly using 'urllib2' and 'shelve' than messing with pseudo-helper stuff like OAuth2WebServerFlow and Storage.

Doing so allows me to check assumptions with 'curl' from the command line, and then code the result in Python.  I can tap into the wealth of blogs and Q & A about OAuth for Google without the fragmentation into all their different spotilly supported libraries (Jave, C#, PHP, etc.)

I have written a fork to [Anton Burnashev's "gspread"](https://github.com/burnash/gspread).

This is my ["Pull Request"](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/75/files)

You should see that I alter almost nothing of Burnashev's code.  I just provide the OAuth stuff, and just for "Installed Applications"

There are 6 different modalities :

1. Login
2. Web Server Applications
3. Client-side Applications
4. Installed Applications
5. Devices
6. Service Accounts

How certain are you that you are using the right one?  It took me a lot of puzzling to realize that mine needed to be an "Installed App", but I'm now realizing I should also support "Devices"

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 flow is slightly different now with the new Google Apps Marketplace experience. Since the admin installs the app, tokens are pre-appoved so you should have to prompt end-users. The are more details at https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/building#use_google_services_from_a_simple_web_server_app